# How to check stdin is empty with no hang?

Tags: c, stdin

I would like my program to read data from either command line option or stdin (redirected). How to check that `stdin` is empty or not then?

Doing `fgetc` hangs my program if `stdin` is empty (waiting for input). Calling `feof` returns false.

Also tried

```
ioctl(0, I_NREAD, &n) == 0 && n > 0
```

but I don't have `I_NREAD` defined (on Raspi, but I want portable).

How to accomplish?

Comment: There is no such concept. `stdin` is just a stream, and either you are at the end of the stream (which happens when it is closed - eg if you press ctrl-D or if you redirected stdin from a file) or not. If you want to deal with the terminal object (not `stdin`), you have to ditch stdin and use proper API for that (open the controlling terminal device `/dev/tty`).

Comment: So it is impossible to write program, which feels, whether it was fed with redirection?

Comment: It is always fed with redirection. When you interact with it directly, it is (typically) redirected from a pty. You can check for that with `isatty(STDIN_FILENO)`.

Comment: I don't know if this would be relevant to you, but canonical unix tools do it the other way around: look for arguments on the command line, and use `stdin` if no input was provided in arguments. Eg `cat foo` will read `foo`, but `cat` will read from stdin.

Comment: Why do you want to check that?

Comment: Like spectras says, Unix command-line tools look for stdin when they are missing any files to work on. But to add to that, they usually treat a single minus sign as the filename for stdin. So if you type `cat -` you get the same as just `cat`

Comment: since you're using a raspberry pi, there should be a non-blocking [#getch()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getch) available in `ncurses.h`. This would let you check for the existence of a character input without blocking. This is not from C's standard lib, however (just noticed the "portable" bit)

Comment: You seem to be talking about non blocking I/O. Specifically, non blocking console IO. Since the entirety of the console is implementation defined, there is no standard way to do this (defined by the C standard). Your best bet of it being portable is to throw in `#ifdef`s to detect the OS and delegate to the correct functions.

Comment: In 2020, you should be using [`poll`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) for unices. Much easier to use and possibly faster than `select`. Still not as fast as `kqueue` but I assume you're not going for absolute performance here. On the windows side.....well, "modern" windows has `select` and `WSAPoll` - neither of which work with console handles. You are supposed to use [`SetConsoleMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode?redirectedfrom=MSDN), or the console API in general.

Answer (score 1):

The `select` function can do it on a POSIX system. On Windows or others you would need other options.

Note that if the shell sets up the pipeline and the operating system schedules the child to run first `(first | child)` it could execute the select and not find any input ready to read.

Note that I changed the timeout from 0 to 100,000 microseconds (0.1 seconds) which helps avoid randomly missing the input. However, if the system is under heavy load it could still fail to detect stdin being ready to read.

See:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

int main() {
  fd_set read_fds;
  struct timeval tv = {0, 100000};
  int fd = fileno(stdin);
  int r;

  FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
  FD_SET(fd, &read_fds);
  r = select(fd + 1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
  if (r > 0) {
    char buffer[256];
    if (fgets(buffer, 256, stdin)) {
      puts(buffer);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do note that doing this will break the program in a lot of ways (from a user perspective). For instance, `otherprog | yourprog` will arbitrarily sometimes see the input from `otherprog` and sometimes not, depending, among other things, on scheduling order.

Comment: @spectras Hmm. Yes you are correct. Maybe using a higher value for timeout would help but if the system is under extreme load and/or swapping, and the child is scheduled first that could still fail.